# Sails.js/Condolidate/Twig Error

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm getting the following error when I request a view in Sails that is using Twig.js:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 TypeError: engine is not a function
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:479:61
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:143:5
    at Promise._execute (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
    at new Promise (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
    at promisify (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:136:10)
    at Function.exports.twig.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:473:10)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:164:27
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:98:5
    at tryToString (fs.js:456:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:443:12)
```

I've tried to fix this many different ways, but I'm still getting the error. I understand Sails should allow me to use anything supported by Consolidate.js, but it just isn't working.

I have:

- cleared the NPM cache
- installed Twig.js (v1.10.4) using NPM, and it's in my package.json

  - Removed and reinstalled twig
- set the engine to 'twig' in `config/views.js`

This is a fresh Sails project without any other customizations or additions.

I'm a little new to node and sails, any help is appreciated!

Comment: pls, provide an example of your controller.

Comment: @GlenSwift This is all just in the homepage view, using the default route that's set up with a new project. No controller, just the `view/homepage.twig` file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a bug with the Sails v0.12.x handling of Twig.  The easiest workaround is to install Consolidate yourself as a dependency of your project:

```
npm install --save consolidate
```

and then in your `config/views.js` do:

```
engine: {
  ext: 'twig',
  fn: require('consolidate').twig
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked with that, but wouldn't let me use `extend`

This ended up working, using Twig directly (now to figure out caching so I don't need to restart the server...)
`engine: {
    ext: 'twig',
    fn: require('twig').__express
},`